# Sitecore cannot save in Experience Editor special characters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

The website is component bases website. In a component I have rich-text and inside of that I have something like 70%. After I add the component to the page the save on the page does not work anymore.

Does someone had an issue like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like also other had same issue :

1) Replace the **/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js** file of your environment with https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk5dhzywuln19t7/ExperienceEditor.js?dl=0

2) Replace the **/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/RibbonPageCode.js** file of your environment with https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk0owx9gmihpgf0/RibbonPageCode.js?dl=0

3) Clear your browser cache.

Original post was here: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2536

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue, contact Sitecore Support and they will be able to provide a fix, reference 84051.

The fix is to [edit a couple of Javascript files](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2536#pi214filter=all&pi214scroll=false). In Sitecore 8.0 update-6:

**/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/RibbonPageCode.js**

In the `initialized` function

replace `ribbonUrl: this.PageEditBar.get("url")`

with `ribbonUrl: decodeURIComponent(this.PageEditBar.get("url"))`

**/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.js**

In the `postServerRequest` function

replace `data: decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(commandContext)))`

with `data: decodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(commandContext))`

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issue we experienced early this year, but the issue we had was fixed in [Sitecore 8.1 Update 2](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Update2/Release%20Notes). The public reference number was 84051.

Answer (score 0):

This post fixed for me. **Note I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2**

**My error:**

`After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'scLayout', line 1, position 2246.`

http://jockstothecore.com/experience-editor-error/

```
postServerRequest: function (requestType, commandContext, handler, async) {

    function normalizeDeviceProp(d) {
        if (typeof(d) !== "object")
            throw new Error("Unexpected presentation details XML: cannot find device property");

        if (d instanceof Array)
            return d;

        var normalized = [];
        normalized.push(d);
        return normalized;
    }

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    // Custom Brainjocks code to fix Experience Editor error.
    var ajaxData = unescape(JSON.stringify(commandContext));
    if (commandContext && commandContext.scLayout) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(commandContext.scLayout);
      if (obj && obj.r) {
          normalizeDeviceProp(obj.r.d).forEach(function (d) {
              if (d.r instanceof Array) {
                  d.r.forEach(function (r) {
                      var val = r["@par"];
                        if (val && val.length > 0) {
                            ajaxData = ajaxData.replace(unescape(val), val);
                        }
                  });
              }

            });
        }
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/" + requestType,
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,
            data: ajaxData
        },
        success: handler,
        type: "POST",
        async: async != undefined ? async : false
    });
}
```